# Set Spinner and Edittext at the same height level

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-edittext, spinner

I have a `spinner` and `edittext` that I add programatically horizontally. The problem is that they're not at the same height level. I set the `height` as `WRAP_CONTENT`, but still not working. Can someone help me with this? Here's my code.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams spinParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
spinParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
params.gravity=Gravity.Center;
```

Answer (score 2):

Give **padding= "0dp"** to spinner. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `gravity` property hope it helps you like as

```
params.gravity=Gravity.Center;
```

Comment: I'm actually using that.  The problem is I want to set that at the same height level.

Comment: use gravity to parent view so that child (`spinner` and `editText`) will auto set to center

Answer (score 0):

use same LayoutParam for spinner and editbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` set `specific height` for both of them

```
TableRow.LayoutParams spinParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 60, 1f);
spinParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 60, 0.5f);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 0);
```